# Why should there be a Big Crunch?

Tags: cosmology, universe, big-bang

Everyone knows it all started with the Big Bang. And then on, all objects have been moving away from each other very fast. And this rate itself is accelerated, according to Hubble's Theory. 
However, I've read that at some point of time, Gravity will surpass all other attractions and it will lead to what we call a 'Big Crunch'. Of course, it's just a hypothesis, but I find it hard to believe, especially because gravity obeys the inverse square law.
I can feel dark matter coming into play(probably), but if dark matter had anything to do with it, the universe wouldn't have been expanding even now- the Dark matter was always there.
Plus, there's much more dark energy than dark matter, which is known to accelerate expansion.

How can the 'Big Crunch' be true?

Comment: As far as we know there will never be a big crunch, so it isn't clear why you heard that it might happen.

Comment: @JohnRennie Prior to the discovery that the expansion of the Universe is speeding up, a Big Crunch was a possible outcome for an overdense Universe. The phrasing of the question makes me think the asker has stumbled onto some out-of-date discussion and is trying to square it with more recent information they’ve read elsewhere.

Comment: @rob You got me right. I had no idea of the sequence of events. I get it now.

Answer (score 2):

Before our astronomical instruments got good enough, the ultimate fate of the universe was not known, and nobody knew for sure whether there was enough matter in it to gravitationally halt the big bang expansion and produce a big crunch.

As pointed out by John Rennie in his comment, our instruments are good enough today to rule out the big crunch, and rule in a far more complicated scenario in which dark matter and dark energy play dominant roles in the universe's evolution.